# Different value of element different class

Tags: jquery, html, math

I'm trying to make a box that has a class depending on the value inside the box.

- if value is greater less then or equal to 3.3 then class = low
- if value is less then 6.6 but higher then 3.3 then class = mid
- if value is higher then 6.6 then class = high

below is the code im trying to use

```
  if ($(".total-score h3").text() <= "3.3") {
    $(".total-score").addClass('low');
}
else if ($(".total-score h3").text() > "3.3" < "6.6") {
    $(".total-score").addClass('mi');
}
else if ($(".total-score h3").text() > "6.6") {
    $(".total-score").addClass('high');
}
```

Comment: Please show some code and markup for what you have tried. If possible please setup a jsfiddle.

Comment: sorry i have added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable to hold CLASS name.
Process input using IF statement and assign appropriate name to CLASS variable
Echo the class name back.

```
$returnedValue = 2.5; //The value being evaluated
$minRangeValue = 3.3; //Minimum Range
$maxRangeValue = 6.6; //Maximum Range
$boxClass = ""; //To hold the class name
if($returnedValue <= $minRangeValue){
    $boxClass = "low";
}
else if($returnedValue > $minRangeValue && $returnedValue <= $maxRangeValue){
    $boxClass = "mid";
}
else if($returnedValue > $maxRangeValue){
    $boxClass = "high";
}

echo '<div class="'. $boxClass .'"> Contenct </div>';
```

Note: Your logic was missing case for when value is exactly 6.6
I have assumed it is class=mid.

Comment: just missing semicolons